# SQL find same value on multiple filelds with like operator

Tags: mysql, sql, search, sql-like

I have this records from my `users` table:

```
user_id first_name  last_name   gender  email
******* **********  *********   ******  *****
229     Natalie     Fern        F   natalie.fern@hotmail.com
```

and I want to search same `First Name` & `Last Name` from `first_name` OR `last_name`.

I have created sql query but not getting record.

```
SELECT *
FROM user_detail
WHERE first_name LIKE '%Natalie Fern%'
OR last_name LIKE '%Natalie Fern%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

You notice that I am passing first & last name from both fields.

Any Idea why I am not getting records?

Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS you are working with?

Comment: You won't get any records because `first_name` is only ever `Natalie` not `Natalie Fern`. Really ... why did you expect this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `LIKE` operator for `first_name` and `last_name` as follows:

```
LIKE '%Natalie Fern%'
```

This will only match strings which contain *anything* followed by 'Natalie Fern' followed by *anything*.  But since the first and last name columns only contain (surprise) the first and last names, your query isn't matching any records.  You can use `CONCAT` to try to match the combination of first and last names:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_detail
WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)
LIKE '%Natalie Fern%'
LIMIT 0, 30
```

If you want to check for people whose first *or* last names could be 'Natalie' or 'Fern', then you could use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_detail
WHERE first_name LIKE '%Natalie%'
OR first_name LIKE '%Fern%'
OR last_name LIKE '%Natalie%'
OR last_name LIKE '%Fern%'
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: Thanks for your great support. I have used first query with `CONCAT` and it is working perfect for me :).

Comment: Glad to help you any way I can :-)

Comment: hopefully you don't have any trailing or leading spaces in the name fields

Answer (score 1):

You get no records because no column contains somethink like "Natalie Fern".

You have to `concat` both columns and you should get the correct result.

But concatination of columns is not a standard. So you have to look in the documantation of your DBMS.

Here some examples:

- MySQL: CONCAT( )
- Oracle: CONCAT( ), ||
- SQL Server: +

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8edd6d/1)

Function

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(8000), @delimiter varchar(20))
RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(   
  position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  value varchar(8000)  
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @index int
SET @index = -1

WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)
  BEGIN 
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text) 
    IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0) 
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
          BREAK 
      END 
    IF (@index > 1) 
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))  
        SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
      END 
    ELSE
      SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))
    END
  RETURN
END
```

Query

```
SELECT * FROM user_detail inner join 
(select value from fn_split('Natalie Fern',' ')) as split_table 
on (user_detail.first_name like '%'+split_table.value+'%' 
or user_detail.last_name like '%'+split_table.value+'%' ;
```

Comment: if You are using Sql server

Answer (score 0):

instead of `LIKE` you can use `LOCATE` to see if the first name is in a string

```
SELECT *
FROM user_detail
WHERE LOCATE(first_name,'Natalie Fern') > 0
OR LOCATE(last_name ,'Natalie Fern') > 0 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform this search with **one search input field**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_detail 
WHERE last_name LIKE '%###VALUE###%' 
OR first_name LIKE '%###VALUE###%' 
OR concat(last_name, ' ', first_name) LIKE '%###VALUE###%' 
OR concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%###VALUE###%';
```